# AS3 Loop Button (Add listener and function)

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, button, listener

How would I go about looping this so I don't have to copy and paste the same code up to 10 or higher?

```
optionsmenu.char01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gochar01);
function gochar1 (event:MouseEvent): void {
    char.gotoAndStop(1);
}
optionsmenu.char02.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gochar02);
function gochar2 (event:MouseEvent): void {
    char.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var callbackGenerator:Function = function(i:int):Function {
  return function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    char.gotoAndStop(i);
  };
};

// Change this according to size of your menu
var menuSize:int = 12;

for (var i:int = 1; i < menuSize; i++) {
  // Prefix with 0
  var index:String = i < 10 ? '0' + i : String(i);

  // Generate the click callback
  var callback:Function = callbackGenerator(i);

  // Add the click event listener
  optionsmenu['char' + index].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callback);
}
```